# Only black opengl 3D faces on TF700, but fine on AVDs

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d

I dusted off my old 3D (openGL EGL) Android app. It was developed back when API v3 was one of the newest. At that time it worked fine on 1.5 (API v3) AVD's and on my physical HTC Magic device. Now after dusting it off and opening the project in a brand new Android dev installation, I needed to do a few changes to make it work. It still has `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />` in AndroidManifest.xml. The app now works fine on 4.4.2 (and others) emulator AVD's. But when I install the app on my Asus TF700 (Android v4.2.1 I believe) all openGL faces are just black (they are supposed to have misc colors, and some have textures). The only reason I can see that the 3D graphics is actually there at all, is that I have a static image behind my transparent 3D GLSurfaceView (my own class, stolen from somewhere back in the days - it was before GLSurfaceView became an actual part of Android SDK). I can see the 3D objects on top of the static image as black objects.
Can anyone come up with any possible explanations that the 3D graphics works fine on AVD's but that all the faces are just back on Asus TF700?

Comment: Does your code check for OpenGL error information (e.g. glGetError)? Shader status and logs? Maybe you should start with that.

Comment: I tried doing glGetError in my main loop. On the virtual devices (where it works) it gives a 0x501 once and then never again. On my Asus (where it does not work) glGetError always gives 0. Do not know how to test for shader status? I get logs in LogCat. I see one single worrying line: 01-31 18:50:00.804: E/(15570): file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!

Comment: For checking shader status and compile logs: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Shader_error_handling. You should also check framebuffer completeness if you are using any (after attaching renderbuffers or textures to it), because that's one typical source of errors: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness. Value 0x501 is GL_INVALID_VALUE, so there's an OpenGL call that is wrong out there. Also on your Asus check in the device settings if there's an option for enabling error reporting (which might be disabled by default to improve performance).